# Jenkins Echo Response(Http status and Body)

Tags: bash, jenkins, curl

Receiving error that `script.sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` on the line that has `def http_status`. What could be an issue?

```
   stage('alert') {
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'org_user_key', variable: 'userKey'), string(credentialsId: 'org_api_key', variable: 'apiKey')]) {
        def response = sh(script: "curl -X POST \
                                --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                                --data '{\"requestType\" : \"getProductAlerts\",\"productToken\" : \"${productToken}\", \"userKey\" : \"${userKey}\"}' \
                                 'https://saas-eu.whitesourcesoftware.com/api/v1.3'", returnStdout: true).trim()

        def http_status = sh(script: "echo \"${response}\" | grep HTTP |  awk '{print \$2}", returnStdout: true)
        sh "echo  \"${http_status}\""
        def body = sh(script: "echo \"${response}\" | grep body", returnStdout: true)
        sh "echo  \"${body}\""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you're missing a single quote after the awk command:

```
def http_status = sh(script: "echo \"${response}\" | grep HTTP |  awk '{print \$2}", returnStdout: true)
```

versus

```
def http_status = sh(script: "echo \"${response}\" | grep HTTP |  awk '{print \$2}'", returnStdout: true)
```